# RestAssured: get key value from json object with specified value

Tags: java, rest-assured, serenity-bdd, rest-assured-jsonpath

In a test case I perform a call with the following response:

```
[
    {
        "ourID": "770050010000000010",
        "date": "2019-03-07",
        "otherValue": null
    },
    {
        "ourID": "770050010000000020",
        "date": "2019-03-07",
        "otherValue": null
    }
]
```

The test is performed by Serenity and I use RestAssured to perform the call:

```
Response response = RestAssuredApiHelper.baseRestCall(headers, baseUrl, path)
                .body(requestBody)
                .post();

assertThat(response.getBody().jsonPath().get("$.[?(@.ourID=='770050010000000010')].date"), contains("2019-03-07"));
```

The assertion is not working, probably because RestAssured uses Gpath instead of JsonPath, but in all the docs i've been reading there are examples of ways this could work.
What am I missing here?

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: [ @ line 1, column 29.
                            $.[?(@.meteringPointEANID=='770050010000000010')].energySource
                               ^

1 error
```

Comment: accept the any one the below answer which helped you so that it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative of using JsonPath with RestAssured is to use the build-in deserialization mechanism of RestAssured.

If you don't know what the return type of the object is you could check this out:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#deserialization-with-generics

The generic solution would look something like this:

```
Response response = RestAssuredApiHelper.baseRestCall(headers, baseUrl, path)
                .body(requestBody)
                .post();

List<Map<String, Object>> objects =  response.getBody().as(new TypeRef<>() {});
Map<String, Object> singleObject = objects.stream().filter((Map<String, Object> object) -> object.get("ourID").equals("770050010000000010"))
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .findFirst().get();

System.out.println(singleObject.get("ourID")); // 770050010000000010
```

If you know what the response object is it, it is even simpeler:

```
List<YourResponseObject> yourResponseObjects = response.getBody().as(new TypeRef<>() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

check with below code:--(i believe that json expression is correct , did not check)

```
Object dateObject = JsonPath.parse(response.getBody().asString()).read("$.[?(@.ourID=='770050010000000010')].date");
String dateString = dataObject.toString();
assertThat(dateString, containsString("2019-03-07"));
```

POM Dependency:---

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The first line shows this error: The method parse(String) is undefined for the type JsonPath

Comment: added dependency check with that

Answer (score 0):

```
assertEquals(response.path("find {it.ourID == '770050010000000010'}.date"), "2019-03-07")
```